# Typo3 Realurl urlcache is messed up by gclid-parameter

Tags: typo3, google-ads-api, realurl

We use Google-Adwords for some campaigns which ads a `gclid=xxxxx` parameter to the URL.
Unfortunately, this messes up the RealUrl tables and when the page is called next time it results in a 404-error.

Is there any way to make RealUrl ignore this particular parameter?

Answer (score 1):

This is claimed to be solved on GitHub:

https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/377

Anyways I still had that problem that the gclid triggers a urldata entry which causes a redirect loop. For now I solved it with removing the gclid from the ignoredGetparameters Filter and then banning it:

```
        'cache' => array( // removed gclid from the filter, then ban it
            'ignoredGetParametersRegExp' => '/^(?:utm_[a-z]+|pk_campaign|pk_kwd|TSFE_ADMIN_PANEL.*)$/'
            'banUrlsRegExp' => '/gclid|tx_solr|tx_indexed_search|(?:^|\?|&)q=/',
        ),
```

Comment: Is there a solution for Typo3 V9 as well? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Install Tool and add the parameter to `[FE][cHashExcludedParameters]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the «gclid» in the install tool - let's see if it helps ;)

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to help - tx_realurl_urldata is growing huuuge...

Answer (score 0):

Since realurl 2, there is a new possibility to control entries to tx_realurl_urldata:

https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#banurlsregexp

```
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
            //[...]
            'cache' => array(
                    'banUrlsRegExp' => '/gclid|tx_solr|tx_indexed_search|(?:^|\?|&)q=/'
            ),
            //[...]
```

Works like a charm, didn't knew until today this option even exists.